# css position need help

Tags: html, css

## html

```
<div class="navigation">
   <a class="active" href="index.html">1</a>
   <a href="index.html">2</a>
   <a href="index.html">3</a>
   <a href="index.html">4</a>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
}    
.navigation a {
  display: block;
}
```

Can anyone help me how to make `<a>` **vertically** center inside `<div class="navigation">`. Number of `<a>`s ranges so I can't just do `padding-top` on `<div class="navigation">`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `vertically` center?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry I mean vertically center... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case. If you wanted it `VERTICALLY` and `HORIZONTALLY` aligned (in all browsers including IE6, maybe no IE5.5 MAC):

[See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/hX75n/)

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  _position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation_inner {
  _position: absolute; 
  _top: 50%; 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
.navigation a {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation"> 
<div class="navigation_inner"> 
   <a class="active" href="index.html">1</a>
   <a href="index.html">2</a>
   <a href="index.html">3</a>
   <a href="index.html">4</a> 
</div> 
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

text-align: center

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}    
.navigation a {
  display: block;
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want it to be vertically centered as well you will need to add another bounding box to be vertically centered:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}    
.wrapper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.navigation a {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<div class="navigation">
<div class='wrapper'>
   <a class="active" href="index.html">1</a>
   <a href="index.html">2</a>
   <a href="index.html">3</a>
   <a href="index.html">4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fact that he was trying to add `padding-top` led me to believe he actually wanted it `vertically` aligned.

Comment: sorry I mean vertically center

Comment: Updated to include examples of both. The reason for the inner wrapper can be viewed here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}    
.navigation a {
  display: block;
}
```